# Geting max value of an array in record - Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a Mongo collection which stores prices for a number of cryptocurrencies.

Each record looks like this:

`1. ticker: string  2. dates: array of datetime.datetime  2. prices: array of float`

I am trying to get the most recent date for a given ticker. I've tried this Python code:

`max_date = date_price_collection.find({"ticker": "BTC"},{"dates":1}).limit(1).sort({"dates",pymongo.ASCENDING})`

But it gives the error:
`TypeError: if no direction is specified, key_or_list must be an instance of list`

How can I get the maximum date for a specific filtered record?

UPDATE:

The following works:

`max_date = date_price_collection.aggregate([ {'$match': {"ticker": ticker}},{'$project': {'max':{'$max': '$dates'}}} ])`

Answer (score 0):

The following query will return the max date value form the `dates` array. Note that this syntax (and feature) is available with MongoDB v4.4 and higher only. This feature allows use [Aggregation Projection (and its operators)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#std-label-method-find-projection) in `find` queries.

```
max_date = date_price_collection.find( { "ticker": "BTC" }, { "_id": False, "dates": { "$max": "$dates" } } )
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works great. I've also managed to get this to work:  `max_date = date_price_collection.aggregate([
            {'$match': {"ticker": ticker}},{'$project': {'max':{'$max': '$dates'}}}
        ])`

Comment: Technically they get the same result and have the same _filter_ and _projection_. Both the methods behave the same way.

Comment: Also, in the aggregation, the `$project` needs the `'_id': False`  to exclude the ``_id value from the output.